# How to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 without GUI (With terminal only)

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

I have a Win 10 installation disk, DVD on priority boot. Grub menu comes up and prevents dvd from booting. Tried to uninstall ubuntu 16.04 with os-uninstaller using a live CD but since I have no desktop (Could not find compatible nvidia drivers) there is no way to run os-installer gui to completely remove ubuntu.

Is there anyway to uninstall from terminal only? I have one sm951 samsung pci-e 128gb drive.

Answer (score 1):

You do not "uninstall" an operating system like it is a piece of normal software.

You use a live dvd session or an installation media to delete the partitions the operating system is on (and then proceed to install a new operating system).

> Grub menu comes up and prevents dvd from booting.

That means you are not booting from the dvd. Either you are booting up wrongly or the dvd is not created correctly. The grub menu should not even show up when you have a bootable dvd and the system is set to boot from the dvd.

Are you using UEFI? Did you insert the dvd and just rebooted the system and thought it would boot from the dvd? Or did you boot the dvd from the bios? The latter should be the method to boot by the way.

---

On my system in the "save&exit" it is called "boot override".

Comment: I am using UEFI, boot menu is boot dvd first, I burned .iso to dvd, inserted into drive, still grub menu comes up. There is no partition, ubuntu straight on drive. Ubuntu live dvd, I can't use os-unistaller without a GUI, I would like to simply format the drive.

Comment: No. On my system you actually tell the BIOS to boot the dvd from inside the BIOS. Not have it 1st in the list.

Comment: I have an msi z170a m6

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace Grub with the Windows bootloader.

To restore Windows bootloader, boot from Windows installation disk, enter Troubleshooting and command line. Run:

```
bootsect /nt60 C:
```

### References

- https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(v=ws.10).aspx

### Disclaimer

I have not tested the command, just found it on the Internet. However, I have used similar instructions to repair Windows 7 boot. I strongly recommend to backup your drive contents before making any changes to bootloader.